# Why does my function start returning nan?

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to run the function until it meets the condition (answer < 0.01) and then report the number of servers needed (c) for that condition.  My program never gets to that point because it starts returning nans halfway through the program.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;

float product (float p);
float answer;


int main()
{
    cout << "Searching for minimum number of servers..." << endl;

    float c;
    float answer;

    do
    {for (c=1; c<220; c++)
      {
        answer = product(c);
        cout << "when c is " << c << " answer is " << answer << endl;
      }
    }while (answer >= 0.01);

    cout << "when c is " << c << " answer is " << product(c) << endl;
    cout << "Minimum number of servers required is " << c << endl;

    return 0;
}

float product (float p)
{
    float temp;
    float result;
    if (p==0)
        answer = 1;
    else
        temp=200*product(p-1);
        result=temp/(temp+p);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: In your base case (i.e: `p == 0`) you never set `result`, you only set `answer`. I am not that familiar with the C++ standard, but for some languages uninitialized values can cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `product` function, you don't set `temp` if `p` equals `0`. This leads to `temp` being uninitialized and contain a seemingly random value when you later calculate `result`.

If you forgot the braces around the indented code after the `else`, you instead leave `result` uninitialized and it will still contain a seemingly random value.

These random values of course includes `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

From your indentation, I expect you meant to write this:

```
float product (float p)
{
    float temp;
    float result;
    if (p==0)
        answer = 1;
    else
    {
        temp=200*product(p-1);
        result=temp/(temp+p);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that I added `{` and `}` around the `else` condition.

Answer (score 0):

1. add braces around the two statements after else

   `else
   {
       temp=200*product(p-1);
       result=temp/(temp+p);
   }`
2. `if(p == 0)
         result = 1`
   Assigning answer = 1 and then returning result, which is uninitialized in this case will give you NaN value when p = 0. Although p will never be zero in the current situation because the argument `c` passed to `product` ranges between 1 and 220.
3. remove the declaration of global variable `answer`. Most likely, you do not need it.